# Swift: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSDictionary' using NSObjects

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Swift 2.1 Xcode 7.1 Alamofire 2.0.2

With the Alamofire function I've described below I'm retrieving the flyers list in a JSON format from the API:

```js
Alamofire.request(Router.GetList()).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in
      var flyers = [Flyer]()

      switch result {
        case .Success(let json):
          if let responseObject = json as? [String: AnyObject], let hits = responseObject["hits"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
print(hits)
            for dictionary in hits {
              flyers.append(Flyer(dictionary: dictionary))
            }

            completionHandler(flyers, nil)
          }
        case .Failure(_, let error):
          completionHandler(nil, error as NSError)
      }
    }
```

the JSON response resulting of the print(hits) is:

```js
[["title": Code 103, 
 "event": {
    "_id" = 54b0561f274441073751;
    name = "Code 103";
    }
],
["title": Code 104, 
 "event": {
    "_id" = 54b0561f274441073752;
    name = "Code 104";
    }
]]
```

as you can see below, the class Flyer have a property ("event") which references two properties of the class Event, `id and name`:

```js
class Flyer: NSObject{

  var title: String?
  var event: Event?

  init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    title    = dictionary["title"] as? String
    event    = Event(dictionary: dictionary["event"] as! [String: AnyObject])
  }
}

class Event: NSObject{

  var id: String?
  var name: String?

  init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

    id              = dictionary["id"] as? String
    name            = dictionary["name"] as? String
  }
}
```

Im getting the next error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x107d50378) to 'NSDictionary' (0x107d4fd60).
```

this error is located in the class Flyer in the line:

```
event    = Event(dictionary: dictionary["event"] as! [String: AnyObject])
```

And I don't know what can I do to solve this issue because the response is not null. Appreciate help

Comment: It seems that the value for the key `event` can be `nil` which is represented by an `NSNull` object. Filter those cases and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following works perfectly in a playground: Try doing a clean and rebuild.

```
let json: AnyObject = [
    "hits": [
        [
            "title": "Code 103",
            "event": [
            "_id": "54b0561f274441073751",
            "name": "Code 103"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "title": "Code 104",
            "event": [
                "_id": "54b0561f274441073752",
                "name": "Code 104"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

class Flyer: NSObject{

    var title: String?
    var event: Event?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        title = dictionary["title"] as? String
        event = Event(dictionary: dictionary["event"] as! [String: AnyObject])
    }
}

class Event: NSObject{

    var id: String?
    var name: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

        id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    }
}

var flyers = [Flyer]()

if let responseObject = json as? [String: AnyObject], let hits = responseObject["hits"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    print(hits)
    for dictionary in hits {
        flyers.append(Flyer(dictionary: dictionary))
    }
}
```